# Magento 2 - How to remove default loader from checkout page when page loading?

Tags: magento2, checkout, loader

I want to remove the default page loader when the page is loading.
I have to remove checkout loader from

> **/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml**

But still, loader coming.

Comment: Did you checked this file ?

**vendor/magento/module-captcha/view/frontend/templates/default.phtml**

Comment: yes but captcha is disable at the moment

Comment: check file module-ui\view\base\web\js\block-loader.js

Answer (score -1):

overwrite of onepage.phtml in one of your themes or modules.

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
```

change to :

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask">
```

Comment: please read question carefully

Comment: Your question is unclear to what's your issue

Answer (score -1):

Open `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml` file and comment loader code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage */
?>
<div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container">
    <!-- <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif')) ?>"
                 alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Loading...')) ?>"
                 style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div> -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
        // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
    <script>
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))) ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getBaseUrl())) ?>');
        })
    </script>
</div>
```

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean`. And check it.

Comment: why you people don't read question carefully.
I have written in bold that i have already remove loader from onepage.phtml

Comment: Clear cache and check it.

Comment: Any why you vote down?????